# html create account form not connecting to node js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, backend

My form is not submitting to the mysql database as it should, when I enter the details and click submit I recieve a http error 405, rather than the account details being stored in the database. I'm not sure what the issue is with my code

CreateAccount.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create account</title>

  <script></script>

</head>

<body>
  

  <h1>Create account</h1>

  <form id="createAccount-form" method="POST" action="/createAccount">

    <label for="username"></label>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
    <p></p>

    <label for="email"></label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required >
    <p></p>

    <label for="password"></label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
    <p></p>

    <label for="Confpassword"></label>
    <input type="password" id="Confpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <p></p>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick=togglePword()> Show Password
    <p></p>

    <button id="createAccountbtn" type="submit">Create account</button>
    
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

CreateAccountConn.js

```
//establish db connection for CREATE ACCOUNT
console.log('part 1');

const mysql = require('mysql');
require("dotenv").config();

const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
});

db.getConnection((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database successfully');
});

/////////
//add a route to createAccount

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const express = require('express');
const ap = express();

console.log('part 2');

ap.use(express.json()); //read req.body.<parameter>
ap.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); //pass form data

console.log('part 3')

ap.post("/createAccount", async (req,res) => {

  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10);

  //validate form inputs
  if (!username || !email || !password){
    return res.status(400).send('Empty fields')
  };

  db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO user_login (id, username, email, password) VALUES (0,?,?,?)',
    [0, username, email, hashPassword],
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error occured while creating account')
        }
    //redirect to user homepage
    res.send('Account created successufully')
    res.redirect('/')
    }
  );
    ap.listen(8080, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port 8080')
    });
  
});
```

from using console.log() statemements I've found the server is not executing past the app.post("/createAccount") line.

Comment: How are you serving `CreateAccount.html`? From another express route on port 8080?

Comment: the createAccountConn.js server should be connecting the form to the mysql db, I'm not sure if that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're making the server listen only when posting to /createAccounts, which can not happen because the server isn't listening.

Move the `ap.listen` function out of the `ap.post` one.

```
ap.post("/createAccount", async (req,res) => {

  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10);

  //validate form inputs
  if (!username || !email || !password){
    return res.status(400).send('Empty fields')
  };

  db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO user_login (id, username, email, password) VALUES (0,?,?,?)',
    [0, username, email, hashPassword],
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error occured while creating account')
        }
    //redirect to user homepage
    res.send('Account created successufully')
    res.redirect('/')
    }
  );  
});

ap.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 8080')
});
```

Comment: i've amended my code and i'm still getting the same error